# Slow performance in Hibernate after some time and I can't find the bottleneck in hibernate statistics

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, hibernate-statistics

I figured out that sometimes my query is very slow. Normally it needs ~200ms. That's why I activated hibernate statistics. But there I couldn't find any place where the time is lost.

I can see that the HQL query needs 44 seconds:

```
2017-05-17 07:20:29,525 DEBUG [org.hibernate.stat.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl] (EJB default - 6) HHH000117: HQL: select generatedAlias0 from X as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.end is null, time: 44610ms, rows: 16721
```

But in Hibernate statistics I can't find any time where it needs 43 seconds. Only the flush needs a little bit longer (~1s).

```
 2017-05-17 07:20:32,963 INFO [org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener] (EJB default - 6) Session Metrics {
     290540 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
     25143 nanoseconds spent releasing 1 JDBC connections;
     372114 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
     3561626 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
     0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
     0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
     0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
     0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
     868055018 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 16721 entities and 0 collections);
     8660 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections) }
```

Also it is very strange that the log entries have a time difference of 3 seconds. Normally the time difference between these two log entries are millisonds.

I also have a second application server (JBoss) which executes the same statement. There I don't have the problem that the query needs long at the same time. So I think the db should be ok.

Sometimes the query needs so long that I get a TransactionCoordinator error:

```
2017-05-16 15:35:34,430 ERROR [com.company.dao.MyDAO] (EJB
default - 17) Error occurs while fetching data:
org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException: This TransactionCoordinator has been closed: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException: This TransactionCoordinator has been closed  
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]     
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]     
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:277)
[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]     
at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getResultList(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:254)
[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
... 
Caused by: org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException: This
TransactionCoordinator has been closed  
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.getTransaction(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:191)
[hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]  
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.isTransactionInProgress(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:167)
[hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]  
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterOperation(SessionImpl.java:476)
[hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]  
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1199)
[hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]  
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
[hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]  
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268)
[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]     .. 198 more
```

Do you have any ideas how I can figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to perform some cpu sampling.

A free and easily available tool to do that is jvisualvm : it is provided with the oracle jdk (in `$JAVA_HOME/bin/`)

Connect to the jvm either locally or remotely, start the cpu sampling, trigger the slow action on your application. Once the action is completed, get a snapshot, and you'll see methods that took time to complete (not every methods, but at least the ones that are the costliest).

This is how to analyze performance issue in general (not only with hibernate). It will work as long as the action you have to analyse last more than ~50ms. The shorter, the less precise the analysis will be (and the more misleading it could be on what is taking time to complete).